# Import Google Calendar agenda into Google Docs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-docs

I have to create a weekly agenda from Google Calendar events each week. The most efficient way I have done it so far is using a template, manually changing the day Mon-Fri, manually copying and pasting each event and details. Is there anyway I can create a Google script/addon where I can just import a calendars agenda for a selected day range?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, this is too broad of a question for a code response, but you can use the [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/apps-script) and the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/integrate-create).

Start by looking up calendar events. The Calendar Docs example shows code for specifically listing upcoming events. You can adjust the arguments (`var optionalArgs`) to include what you need.

Once you have found your events, use the Create Files Docs to create a Google Doc with the calendar events.

Note how you can use Google Apps Scripts with the Calendar API, as seen in the example I linked. I'm not sure about using the Drive REST API, so you may need to write all of this program in a Drive REST API supported language or download the results from one language and then upload with another.